# What are some good buildings to get rid of my excess Qs and Zs

Tags: lexicopolis-a-b-city

In the game you're gonna build a large supply of Qs and Zs:

[image: Image of the game highlighting the problem]

What are the buildings I can use to get rid of these letters.

Comment: 'Zoo' works for Z.  Also 'Ziggurat'.  'Quarry' works for Q.  I don't have a full list though.

Comment: Progress! Why didn't I think of zoo =/

Comment: Zen Garden works for Z. Came with the newest update!

Comment: mosque, and plaza